# How to read gzip-File with fopen in octave 3.2.4?

Tags: octave

I need to open a gzip file with `fopen`.  The manual (`help fopen`) explains to add `b` and `z` to the mode string:

```
[f, msg] = fopen('file.gz', 'rbz')
```

results to the error:

```
f = -1
msg =
```

`rb` and `r` work separately, but not with `z`.  Do i misunderstand the manual?

An example file can be generated by

```
echo -e "1,2\n2,3\n3,4\n4,3\n5,5" | gzip > file.gz
```

The octave version 3.2.4 is caused by my operating system:  Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Comment: if you do `[fid, msg] = fopen (filepath, "rbz")`, what is the error message in the second output argument? Also, since that's a very old version of Octave, does `help fopen` has the  `z` option? Or did you got it from the online manual which is for the latest version?

Comment: The message is empty.  `help fopen` has the `z` option.  The old version is caused by the LTS version of Ubuntu (12.04)

Comment: then use Octave's PPA to upgrade for the latest version.  See the wiki page for [Debian systems](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) for instructions. Anyway, it seems you're doing it correctly so the problem may be with you file. Can't you upload it somewhere so we can try it?

Comment: Does your version have a `gunzip` function?  If so, you should be able to write your own function that unpacks, reads, and then removes the temp file (if needed).

Comment: I have a `3.2.3` where this `z` option does not work.  But in '3.4.3` it is does fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function data = zcatcsvfile(filename, firstline)
    data = [];
    [status, content] = system(cstrcat('zcat ', filename, ' | tail -n +', num2str(firstline)));
    data = str2num(content);
endfunction
```

Use this function to read a gzipped file `filename` and read as first line `firstline`.  If the file has a header of 5 lines:

```
data=zcatcsvfile('data.gz', 6)
```